# structure preserving map

Tags: abstract-algebra

If I have a mapping $f$ between two sets $A, B$ where $f$ maps solutions of multivariate polynomial to known solution with $x_1<x_2..\&    y_1<y_2...$ $$f:c_1(1+x_1+..+x^k_1)(1+x_2+..x_2^{k_2})....(1+x_m+...) \rightarrow c_1(1+y_1+..+y^k_1)(1+y_2+..+y_2^{k_2})....(1+y_m+...)$$ and I know that if I remove $(1+y_m+...+y_m^{k_m}) $ that the solution still holds in B does this imply that removing $(1+x_m+...+x_m^{k_m})$ should still hold as well ? If it helps, removing $(1+y_{m-1}+...)$ still holds all the way to leaving only the $y_1$ terms. If it could hold under certain conditions what would that be or need to be proven? Would I have to show that the mapping hold from $B$ to $A$ also?